# How to remove php extension form URL .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

It removes .html extension from urls, how do I remove .php as well with the same code?

Comment: You could check if it works -  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this modified rule

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.(php|html|htm)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html|htm)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there's a shorter way to solve this out there but in this is how I remove php extension at the moment:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1\.php
```

Update:

Try this since you would like to main existing code

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes, it is not hard to find, but I'm looking for an option to keep the original code with a slight modification

Comment: ah right. Have you tried adding: 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]

which is just changing the extension with the same code